# Excel Pivot Table Calculated Field depending on Column Name

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to create a calulated pivot field, which calculates an average value of some columns depending on the the column name?
I have there a pivot table which has year columns and I want to create an average value for the years x-2019, but it should not include the year 2020.

[image]

Some of the data provides just years from 2017-2020, but some of it from 2000-2020, means the amount of year columns can change depending on the filter setting of the country.

If there is no way to create this via a calculated field, what else is the best way to do such a calculation to adapt it automatically to the changing amount of years?

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzw2c78ol094zlr/Excess-mortality-worldwide.xlsx?dl=0) is the according Excel file which takes the data from the Financial Times Github repository "[coronavirus-excess-mortality-data](https://github.com/Financial-Times/coronavirus-excess-mortality-data)".

The idea is to compare the mortality in 2020 with the average value of the years before, like you can see it on the sheet "Austria" of the provided Excel file which I created manually, but it cannot update dynamically.